# What does "into the end of next year" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wonder if it means "from now to the end of next year".

As a result, Thin expects the greenback to strengthen another 5 to 10 percent **into the end of next year** as Trump likely implements business-friendly policies and the Fed raises rates.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2016/12/15/euro-could-finally-reach-parity-with-the-dollar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that Thin expects the US dollar to continue to strengthen in the last few months of next year (at the time of writing, 2017).